# how to solve gradle synchronisation fatal error

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I got this below error when trying to build android project .

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'ArchersMobile'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.6.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.6.1
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.6.1
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.6.1.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/26.6.1/shared-26.6.1.pom
> > Already seen doctype.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 0):

This works in most cases :

1. File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
2. Restart Android Studio
3. Rebuild

If this doesn't work, then delete the `.gradle` file in the home directory and restart Android Studio and rebuild the project.